# My code is not fully running when a button is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

So when a button it pressed it's supposed to find the string word on a webpage and if it does have that string then it's supposed to find another string on the webpage and then add that string in a listbox. Although when I press the button it does everything it's supposed to do but add the string to the listbox. And if you press the button a second again it adds the string that it was supposed to add before. Here is my code. I'm not sure why this is happening.

This is the code where I'm getting the problems.

```
         foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("h2"))
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        Debug.WriteLine("2");
                        if (el.GetAttribute("classname") == "notranslate")
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("3");
                            groupname = el.InnerText;
                            listBox1.Items.Add(groupname);
                            listBox1.Items.Add(Empty);
                            Debug.WriteLine(groupname);
                        }
                    }
```

Here is a link to the full code if you would like that.
http://pastebin.com/1Y8NihRS

Comment: I'm sure that if you set a breakpoint and use the debugger to step through the code, you will find the problem.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and update sample in your post according to it.

Comment: Edited it. Should look a bit better.

Comment: @Bootsie123 -- Not every page contains your "word" variable.  Since we don't know your end goal, the code seems to be working fine.